# How to use greater than or less than in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

if the resultText is equal to clownamt(@"34") i want to  display animation and if the resultText is other than value of clownamt then single image. This is my requirements.

```
-(void)clownDanceAnimation {
if (counter == 1 && [resultText.text isEqualToString:clownamt]){
    [self hideObjectAnimationDidStart];

    NSArray *dashBoy1;
    dashBoy1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a20001.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"a20002.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"a20003.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"a20004.png"], nil];
    stgImage1.animationImages = dashBoy1;
    stgImage1.animationDuration = 1;
    [stgImage1 startAnimating];

}
else if((counter==1 && resultText.text > clownamt)) {
    stgImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clownDanceHide.png"];

}
}
```

But first time is perfectly working and the second time whatever the clownamt is present (whether it is 34 or other value ) it display only that single image instead of animation function. Each and every time i will run that simulator works only else part instead of if statement.

Comment: Are you changing the counter value any where in the application ? Check the counter value during the second time?

Comment: check the counter value

Comment: You need to check both clownamt and counter value while executing 2nd time> just use break point and po do display it in console

Comment: convert string into integer value and then compare your condition will be correct... like [resultText.text intValue] this will make your string into integer then your condition will work. :)

Comment: first i used integer only i.e., @"34" this is condition satisfied.  but how to give in else function. (resultText.text > @"34") is this correct...

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings with `<` or `>`. This should get you what you're looking for:

```
NSString *string1;
NSString *string2;
if ([string1 compare:string2 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // numeric value of string1 > numeric value of string2
} else if ([string1 compare:string2 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // numeric value of string1 < numeric value of string2
} else {
    // numeric value of string1 == numeric value of string2
}
```

Just make sure neither string is `nil` first. Here's the [link to Apple's documentation on the method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3aoptions%3a) for more info.